# What is <SubType>Designer</SubType> for in .csproj?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, csproj

What is Designer for in .csproj?

I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c014433-95e1-46ba-8a8c-5dceaabb7ad3/what-is-ltsubtypegtdesignerltsubtypegt-for-in-csproj?forum=csharpide) post, but the links to some kind of a documentation are broken there, so I am not able to read what this is.

Could someone provide a definition for the SubType, please? Maybe a more in depth explanation.

Comment: Nothing very special.  It helps the IDE to figure out what kind of file this is, beyond what it can figure out from the filename extension.  With SubType it knows it is a support file that should be shown as a child of a project item in the Solution Explorer window.  And Designer indicates its default action when you double-click it, you get the design-view of the file.  Links will be broken, Microsoft is retiring the old schema, best to not pay too much attention to it.

Comment: Good question. It was the only thing that changed in my project file and I was wondering if there was a reason to keep the change and update the file in the repo but it looks like it probably isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

At least for WPF/UWP/XAMARIN/MAUI project it shows that you can jump from .xaml.cs to .xaml designer via view designer option in the menu (simple shitf+F7 shortcut) can be used. + Hans answer. [Menu option view designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Gg9.png)