# What is the meaning of ItemGroup Compile 'SubType' in .csproj?

Tags: c#, msbuild

Sometimes Visual Studio 2022 generates XML like this in my SDK-style .csproj after I add a project item:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="MyFile.xaml.cs">
    <SubType>Code</SubType>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

I have seen references to other values for the SubType tag in other questions on this site too. I cannot find any official documentation or description of the tag's purpose. I would expect to find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#compile) but there's nothing.

What is the `SubType` tag for and where is it documented? I am curious about the tag in general, not just the `Code` value in my example above.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754449/what-is-subtypedesigner-subtype-for-in-csproj

Comment: @KlausGütter thank you yes I read that one. But that question is about a particular value for SubType, rather than the meaning of the tag in general.

Comment: `SubType` is not documented for [`Compile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#compile) or as general metadata. The [`ResolveAssemblyReference` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/resolveassemblyreference-task?view=vs-2022) will check for `SubType` metadata but it seems that the `Compile` Item wouldn't be passed to the that task. Is there a `MyFile.xaml` item with a `SubType`? It might used by the Visual Studio IDE.